# how exactly is the recursion working in this code

Tags: python

I have this code , and it is not mine , I saw it online and i am wondering how is the recursion working , can someone please explain !

(this function accepts a list of integers(distances) and a value 'r' lets say 10) and it returns all the possibilities of how we can reach 100 using the distances) lets say the list is `[3,5,2,5]` and the value `r` is  `10` ! so to make `10` we need `[5,5]` or `[3,2,5]` ,this is the code:

```
def greedy(r, distances):
if r < 0:
    return []
if r == 0:
    return [[]]
solutions = []
for last_distance in d:
    combos = greedy(r - last_distance, d)
    for combo in combos:
        combo.append(last_distance)
        if(not solutions.__contains__(combo)):
            solutions.append(combo)
return solutions
```

i hope i made my self clear

Comment: Recursion is just a function call where caller and callee are the same. Recursion works just like any other function call.

Comment: I don't even think this is recursion...

Comment: he is recalling greedy

Comment: You should properly indent your code. Badly indented Python code is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using python print function

```
print("")
```

At multiple locations to actually see the recursion happening. You would get a better idea than someone trying to explain it to you.

Although the function itself is quite simple. For every element in distances, the function subtracts the element from the required `r` value and checks the value with the if conditions. 
If `r` value is zero ie, the for some elements in distance, their sum is `r`, a multi list is returned, which furthermore has the said elements.

At the end, the complete list of  elements whose sum adds to `r` are appended to `solution` list and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Say that given a list `distances0` of length `n`, you are able to return all tuples `i1,..,in`from the list that sums to a number `r` for any number `r`.

You would like to do the same for a list `distances` of length `n+1`.
Since you know how to solve the problem for a list of size `n`, you will do the following: for every element `last_distance` of `distances`, return all tuples `i1,...,in` that sums to `r-last_distance` from a list `distances0` which is similar to `distances` but without the element `last_distance` (and hence of length `n`).

I think there might be some mistakes in the code, here should be a working version:

```
def greedy(r, distances):
    if r < 0:
        return []
    if r == 0:
        return [[]]
    solutions = []
    for i in range(len(distances)):
        d = distances[:i]+distances[i+1:]
        last_distance = distances[i]
        combos = greedy(r - last_distance, d)
        for combo in combos:
            combo.append(last_distance)
            if(not solutions.__contains__(combo)):
                solutions.append(combo)
    return solutions
```